# angularJS - variable component templates

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to define a variable template for a component in angularJS 1.6?
Something like this:

```
<div class="test">
    <{{$ctrl.GetElement()}}> 
</div>
```

for cases in which I want to decide in runtime what the template be like.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: you might looking for `$compile` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Comment: This is possible, but is totally against the design goals of angular.  This is the realm of Directives and Components;  This kind of code with functions that execute inside expressions will grind your app performance wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example of a "variable template" using `$compile`. Let's define a "generator" directive which will be able to generate other directives:

```
app.directive('createDirective', function($compile) {
    return {
        scope: {
            directiveName: '@'
        },
        link: function(scope, element) {
            var newHtml = '<' + scope.directiveName +'></ '+ scope.directiveName +'>';
            element.append($compile(newHtml)(scope));
        }
    };
});
```

This "generator" directive takes in a string (via the attribute "directive-name"), assembles new HTML, compiles it, and appends the resulting HTML to the generator directive.

I've defined a separate directive named "Hello", which I want to be called dynamically from the generator directive:

```
app.directive('hello', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, element) {
            element.append("Hello!");
        }
    }
});
```

Now, we can use the generator directive to compile the "Hello" directive

```
<div create-directive directive-name="hello"></div>
```

which results in this generated HTML

```
<hello class="ng-scope">
    <!-- hello-->
    Hello!
</hello>
```

In addition, we can pass a variable from a controller to the generator directive in a similar way:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.newDirective = "from-controller";
});
```

And in the HTML:

```
<div create-directive directive-name="{{newDirective}}"></div>
```

Be sure to take a look at the [$compile documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile).

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/55bKOc61EEsHdRQpsB2q?p=preview)